# Array Reshaping Problem using sklearn module

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to execute my ml model and trying to reshape the array in it by executing this code.
but this problem is occuring, can anyone please help??

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)
(np.array((x_train.reshape(len(x_train),1),x_test.reshape(len(x_test),1)),1))
```

I try to reduce the test size but it din't work

Comment: What is `this problem is occuring`, you didn't provide an error message. Also make sure that your question contains all the information needed to reproduce your problem: what is `x` and `y` for example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and more detail on how to improve your question